# Simple dialog on pressing Floating action button for Flutter

Tags: flutter, mobile, flutter-layout, flutter-animation, flutter-test

Im a beginner in flutter and i need some help in figuring what went wrong with my code here

i am trying to make the floating action button display a simple dialog (and add content) but i am unsure why i am unable to bring the simple dialog out when i press the FAB.I am aware that it has to be within the stateless widget but i cant seem to insert the FAB within the stateless/stateful widget segment.Is there a work-around for this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
 void main() {
    runApp(MaterialApp(
     debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
     home: Scaffold(
       bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
         child: Text(
           "test bottom",
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Color(0xffFFFFFF),
             fontSize: 10,
            ),
           textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          ),
          color: Colors.blueGrey[600],
          ),
         backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent[50],
             appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('test'),
           backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey[600],
        ),
        body: SoundTest(),
       floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
         child: Icon(Icons.priority_high),
         onPressed: () {
           print('hello');
        },
       ),
     ),
      ));
     }

 class SoundTest extends StatelessWidget {
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return Column(
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,

  children: <Widget>[
    Expanded(
      child: FlatButton(
        child: Image.asset('images/softsound.png'),
        onPressed: () {
          final player = AudioCache();
          player.play('clicksoft.wav');
          showDialog(context: context,
          );
        },
      ),
    ),
    Expanded(
      child: FlatButton(
          child: Image.asset('images/loudsound.png'),
          onPressed: () {
            final player = AudioCache();
            player.play('clickloud.wav');
          }),
         )
        ],
      );
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

## Method 1

Take a `StatefulWidget`,

**Complete example,** Find Complete Code [here](https://gist.github.com/raviganwal/773d98278eca141b312943c28b180db6)

```
class Login extends StatefulWidget {
  Login({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<Login> {


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(onPressed: (){_showDialog();}),
    );
  }

  void _showDialog() {
    // flutter defined function
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        // return object of type Dialog
        return AlertDialog(
          title: new Text("Alert Dialog title"),
          content: new Text("Alert Dialog body"),
          actions: <Widget>[
            // usually buttons at the bottom of the dialog
            new FlatButton(
              child: new Text("Close"),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              },
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

## Method 2

Declare a `_scaffoldKey`

```
  var _scaffoldKey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
```

assign `_scaffoldkey` to your `Scaffold`,

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      body: Container(),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(onPressed: (){_showDialog();}),
    );
  }
```

then pass `_scaffoldKey.currentContext` to dialog's like this `context:_scaffoldKey.currentContext,`

```
  void _showDialog() {
    // flutter defined function
    showDialog(
      context: _scaffoldKey.currentContext,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        // return object of type Dialog
        return AlertDialog(
          title: new Text("Alert Dialog title"),
          content: new Text("Alert Dialog body"),
          actions: <Widget>[
            // usually buttons at the bottom of the dialog
            new FlatButton(
              child: new Text("Close"),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              },
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Dear Sir, thanks for the quick reply.There seems to be a problem, it says that context (in your code) is undefined.Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: flutter: ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY GESTURE ╞═════════════════════
flutter: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/localizations.dart': Failed assertion: line 447 pos 12: 'context !=
flutter: null': is not true.
flutter:
flutter: Either the assertion indicates an error in the framework itself, or we should provide substantially
flutter: more information in this error message to help you determine and fix the underlying cause.
flutter: In either case, please report this assertion by filing a bug on GitHub:
flutter:   https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new?template=BUG.md

Comment: above is when i tested method 2.As for method 1,too many errors.i don't think its feasible

Comment: although codes I used here are working fine. but you seem you very new in futter. so I have created a working sample here https://gist.github.com/raviganwal/773d98278eca141b312943c28b180db6